# How can I take value from div and use it in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, alert

I have a div and some number. To get that number I used jQuery `.text();`. I can `alert` and get the correct number, but when I use like this

```
array[$(this).text()];
```

I get error. Why?

```
<div> 2 </div> 

array[$("div").text()]; ------- This doesn't work why?

alert($("div").text()); ------- This works..
```

Keep in mind that I have values in the array! I want to get value from the array therefore I am trying to get it from the div value, which is number 2 and i am calling array to give me the value . Array[2] but why is this not working  array[$("div").text()];

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What did you expect that code to do?  What exactly do you mean by "use it in array"; **how** do you want to use it?

Comment: If that's your whole code: because `array` is not defined.

Comment: There is an easy way to make your question clear: provide a complete example. Write what you expect, e.g. "When I do this I expect to get the value x", and what happens with your current code, "but instead I get y/the error z". Since we don't know your level of knowledge of JS, it's impossible for us to provide you with proper help if we only have a vague explanation and incomplete code.

Comment: To come back to your question: you say you are getting an error, which error? Syntactically the code is correct so it can only be a runtime error. And that would only be the case if either `array` is not defined or `$` doesn't return a jQuery object with method `text`.

Comment: Actually, I missed the space and therefore i got undefined

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the array KEY depending on the DIV value...

```
var key =  +$('div').text(); // Number
alert( array[key] );         // Whatever array[N] holds as value
```

Example:

```
<div> 2 </div>
```

```
var array = ["Zero","one","Two","three"];
var key = +$('div').text();

alert( array[key] ); // "Two"
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gulic/1/edit)

---

Comment: If adding the value is what the op wants.

Comment: No no, I know that, I have already some values in array, but I need to get value from array and in order to do that I have to write like this array[1]; but in my case I am taking the number from the div and trying to call the value from array..

Comment: @user3478007 have you tried to alert `array[0]` ?

Comment: I think you are still misunderstanding what the op wants. They want to use the content of the element as *index* into the array.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah... now after the OP edit seems more clear! Thanks though for the note!

Comment: No no, I have values in the array and I am trying to get them with the div value. div = 2 as you can see. if I call array[2] i should get an value

Comment: why do you put + in front of $('div').text();?

Comment: @user3478007 to convert String to Number.

Answer (score 2):

you have some spaces in your div , try to trim your `text()` using `$.trim()`

working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxM3g/)

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv"> 2 </div>
```

jQuery

```
var data = ["A","B","C"];

alert(data[$.trim($("#myDiv").text())]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array[2]` is defined? `text()` returns `' 2 '`. And `array[' 2 ']` is not defined.

If so, you need to convert it to a number:

```
array[parseInt($(this).text(), 10)] ....
```

Comment: That could be it, though that doesn't explain why the OP gets an *error* (maybe just poorly formulated).